# Linking python code with html code for styling

Tags: python, html, configure

I want to link my python code file with my html code file to perform styling on the python output.

My html code looks like this (I tried to configure my page with github):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>linking html and python</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <py-config>
        [[fetch]]
        from = "https://github.com/PrabhaanGoyal/Python.github.io.git"
        files = ["Calculator.py"]
    </py-config>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the "link rel" from the pyscipt main website pyscript.net.

My python file name is "Calculator.py"

I get the error:

```
(PY0001): Fetching from URL https://github.com/PrabhaanGoyal/Python.github.io.git/hello.py failed with error 'Failed to fetch'. Are your filename and path correct?
```

Either I have not configured my file properly with github, or there is problem in the html code.

Comment: That's not the right format for a raw content URL. It should look something like `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PrabhaanGoyal/Python.github.io/master/Calculator.py`, like when you click the Raw button when viewing a source code file in GitHub.

Comment: I am now viewing the source code file. I just ran my html program which was supposed to execute the my python code which I linked with it.

Comment: I know you're not viewing it, you're trying to download and execute the Python source code at that URL. Your URL is wrong though, since obviously it didn't work in Python, and when you paste it into a browser, it also says Not Found. The URL I provided should be the one that allows Python to download the file; I was not talking about viewing the file in the browser, of course. I was merely saying that the *same* URL you use to browse the raw version of the file is the URL you should be using in your Python script. I'm very aware of what you are trying to do, but you misunderstood.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I'll try again.
Thank you!!